# Dynamically set the EC2 Instance Type per Environment using ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, ebextensions

I want to create a EC2 instance type `t3.medium` on all environments and `m5.large` on production.

I'm using `.ebextensions` (YAML) like so:

option 1:

```
Mappings:
  EnvironmentMap:
    "production":
      TheType: "m5.large"
      SecurityGroup: "foo"
      ...
    "staging":
      TheType: "t3.medium"
      SecurityGroup: "bar"
      ...

option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
    InstanceType: !FindInMap
      - EnvironmentMap
      - !Ref 'AWSEBEnvironmentName'
      - TheType
    SecurityGroups:
      - {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EnvironmentMap", {"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "SecurityGroup"]}
```

Option 2:

```
    InstanceType: {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EnvironmentMap", {"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "EC2InstanceType"]}
```

Option 3:

```
    InstanceType:
      - {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EnvironmentMap", {"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "EC2InstanceType"]}
```

## Results

Option 1 fails with Invalid Yaml (but I took this from this AWS [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html).

Option 2 and 3 fail with the same problem.
The FindInMap function is not "called":
`Invalid option value: '{"Fn::FindInMap":["EnvironmentMap","EC2InstanceType"]},{"Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName"}' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'InstanceType'): Value is not one of the allowed values: [c1.medium, c1.xlarge, c3.2xlarge, ....`

It tries to interpret the whole function/thing as a string.

<strike>For the `SecurityGroups` property it works, for `InstanceType` it does not.</strike>

I can't do it dynamically and I can't find how to achieve this neither on AWS doc, SO, or anywhere else. I would assume this is simple stuff. What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

Option 4: using conditionals

```
Conditions:
  IsProduction: !Equals [ !Ref AWSEBEnvironmentName, production ]

option_settings:

  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    InstanceType: !If [ IsProduction, m5.large, t3.medium ]
    SecurityGroups:
      - {"Fn::FindInMap": ["EnvironmentMap", {"Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"}, "SecurityGroup"]}
```

Error: `YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: could not determine a constructor for the tag !Equals in...`

But this comes from documentation on [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) and [if](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if).

---

EDIT 2:

I eventually found out that the option `InstanceType` is [obsolute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration) and we should use:

```
aws:ec2:instances
  InstanceTypes: "t3.medium"
```

But alas, this does not solve the problem either because I cannot use the replacement functions here as well (`Fn:findInMap`).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `FindInMap` does not work in `option_settings` is the fact that only **four intrinsic functions are allowed** there (from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html)):

- Ref
- Fn::GetAtt
- Fn::Join
- Fn::GetOptionSetting

I'm not convinced that `SecurityGroups` worked. I think your script failed before `FindInMap` in `SecurityGroups` got chance to be evaluated.

However,  **I tried to find a way** using [Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html). The closes I got was with the following `config` file:

```
Mappings:
  EnvironmentMap:
    production:
      TheType: "t3.medium"
    staging:
      TheType: "t2.small"

Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      InstanceType:
        ? "Fn::FindInMap"
        :
          - EnvironmentMap
          - 
            Ref: "AWSEBEnvironmentName"
          - TheType
```

Although this is a step closer, it **ultimately fails** as well. The reason is that when EB is jointing our `Resources` config file with its own template, it produces the following:

```
"InstanceType": {
  "Ref": "InstanceType", # <--- this should NOT be here :-(
  "Fn::FindInMap": [
    "EnvironmentMap",
    {
      "Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"
    },
    "TheType"
  ]
},
```

instead of

```
"InstanceType": {
  "Fn::FindInMap": [
    "EnvironmentMap",
    {
      "Ref": "AWSEBEnvironmentName"
    },
    "TheType"
  ]
},
```

And this happens because the original `InstanceType` (before the joint operation) is:

```
"InstanceType":{"Ref":"InstanceType"},
```

Therefore, EB **instead of replacing** `InstanceType` with our custom `InstanceType` provided in our config file, it just merges them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i learned something already. I would assume this is a basic operation. Use smaller, cheaper EC2 on dev, use a bigger faster EC2 on prod. How come this is so hard? How are we supposed to achieve the same effect then ?

Comment: @Vetras I don't have answer currently.  I also tried using [Fn::GetOptionSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-getoptionsetting) but had no luck. Maybe there is other way, simpler. I don't know for now. Sorry.

Comment: @Vetras As a side note, if you used CloudFormation for provisioning your EB env,  you could do it easily there, not from `.ebextensions`.

Comment: Right now the whole project is ebextensions and is a bit large.
I am planning on cloning this into terraform sometime soon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone else searching, instead of trying to dynamically or conditionally set the instance type in an ebextensions config file, you can just entirely omit that config option and instead include the `--instance_type` flag in the `eb create` command (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html#eb3-createoptions):

```bash
eb create --instance_type t4g.small [...]
```

Now since your ebextensions has no reference to the instance type/size, when you deploy, the original option won't get overridden. You can change the instance type within the running environment through the web console.

Comment: This helps in the case you are creating stuff with the CLI. Not when you have a running env and try to update the IAC and deploy -- right?

Comment: Yes, I create the environment with the CLI and then I can update the instance type in the web console.